# Obter o label do optgroup e o value do option e mostra numa div com Jquery

Tags: jquery, select, label, value

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="fruta">      
        <option value="banana">banana</option>
        <option value="uva">uva</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="legume">
        <option value="batata">batata</option>
        <option value="cenoura">cenoura</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<div id="label_value"></div>
```

Gostaria em JQuery pegar o valor do label e value e jogar numa div.

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var label = $(this).find(':selected').closest('optgroup').attr('label');
    $('#label_value').html(label);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cujweb2h/

O código vai buscar a `option` selecionada e depois sobe no DOM para ir buscar o `optgroup` dessa `option`. Aí lê o atributo `label`.

Comment: Olá Sergio, tem como já deixar escrito na div as primeiras opções? Tipo:

No html a primeira opção é fruta banana.
Tem como já aparecer antes do usuário escolher outra coisa?

Comment: @ProfºRafaelFerreira sim, é so fazer `$('select').change();` -> http://jsfiddle.net/cujweb2h/1/

Comment: Mais uma vez, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Sergio, muito obrigado. Estou aprendendo agora a fazer JS e tô inventando certas situações e práticar. Eu até queria que aparecesse não só o atributo "label", mas junto dele aparecesse o atributo "value" do option. Aí fiz as seguintes alterações

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('select').change(function () {
    var label = $(this).find(':selected').closest('optgroup').attr('label');
    var value = $(this).find(':selected').closest('option').attr('value');
    $('#label_value').html(label+value);
});
});
```

Comment: Vi agora que deste esta resposta também. Penso que isto é uma continuação da pergunta, e não uma resposta certo? Se fôr o caso deves apagar. Mas em relação ao que referes podes usar o `this.value` dentro dessa função para teres o `option` escolhido. Assim: http://jsfiddle.net/cujweb2h/2/

Comment: Nada. Foi só pra agradecer e mostrar uma pequena alteração que  fiz e não pode colocar codigos nos comentários. Mas obrigado pela dica. Sou novo no forum, ainda tenho muito que aprender.